# Python: 2D alternative for InterpolatedUnivariateSpline

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

[InterpolatedUnivariateSpline](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.html) allows extrapolation:

> **ext** : int or str, optional Controls the extrapolation mode for elements not in the interval defined by the knot sequence.
>
> - if ext=0 or ‘extrapolate’, return the extrapolated value.
> - if ext=1 or ‘zeros’, return 0

I have a 1D grid, but I need extrapolation, which is why I used this function despite the existence of interpolation methods specifically written for grids. I was using it as follows:

```
interpolateMe = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(
    np.hstack((0, x[:, idx)),
    np.hstack((0, c[:, idx)), k=1)
```

Now, I have a similar problem, but instead of a vector, I have a matrix

```
zeros2d = np.zeros((1, x.shape[1],))
interpolateMe = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(
    np.hstack((0, x[:, :])),
    np.hstack((0, c[:, :])), k=1)
```

However, this won't work as the function only works with vector input:

```
too many axes: 2 (effrank=2), expected rank=1
```

So now I'm wondering what to do. This is part of a bottleneck, so efficiency is important.

I'm fine with doing 2 successive 1D interpolations, if that's the most efficient. I had a look at [SmoothBivariateSpline](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline), but it's lack ability of dealing with extrapolation is a major drawback.